# Why a JS file is publicly available for one file but not the other even after declaring it as public?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

So I'm fairly new to node and express but I have this code in my **server.js** file.

```
//view folder declared
//view engine declared
app.use(express.static('public'));//js file folder location
//routes declared
```

In my home view I simply have this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <script defer src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <a href="home/room">Go to Room</a>


</body>

</html>
```

for this view, it **correctly** loads my javascript file called **script.js**

but for the *similar view* ***(room.ejs)*** in the **same folder**, I get 404 for the **script.js** file

**The view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>Room</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

***I simply don't understand why, am I missing something?***

Comment: I got this to work by adding /script.js in the room.ejs file, but I still don't understand why it works for the home file and not this.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to determine what absolute URL the browser is resolving the relative URL to in the two different cases.